# I clear the cache after deployment to production but also lose my app cache. How do I exclude my pool while seeing new symfony code updates?

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.4

To deploy, I 'git pull' then 'bin/console cache:clear' to see the updates to my website.

It works, but I don't want to lose MY cache pool's data when this happens.  (I cache results to 3rd party api calls)

I expected the symfony command to clear it's own cache stores only and not the cache items I've submitted since they are still valuable to me after I clear the symfony cache to deploy new code.

Q1: How can I clear all the caches except my app's cache pool 'api_call_cache_pool' below?

Q2: Is there a different cache clear call I should use instead of 'bin/console cache:clear'?

Q3: Would api_call_cache_pool not be cleared if it's adapter was Redis instead of filesystem?

```
framework:
    cache:

        directory: '%kernel.cache_dir%/pools'   

        app: cache.adapter.filesystem
        system: cache.adapter.system

        pools:
            api_call_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.filesystem
                default_lifetime: 6000
                tags: true
```

Answer (score 0):

As `cache:clear` will clear all your caches, I would reccomend to create a script by leveraging the `php bin/console cache:pool:list` and exclude what you want to exclude (`api_call_cache_pool` in your example).

I'm not sure why a "blacklist" policy can't be applied here.

(Or, maybe, use `cache.system_clearer` and `cache.app_clearer` can be enough; you should try by yourself)

Comment: Does not look like cache:clear will clear all cache including all the pools though. I cannot find any document regarding that. Do you have any additional information that can confirm it? I tried on my app and cache:clear does not seem to clear pools at all.

Comment: @mr1031011 "_The global clearer clears all the cache items in every pool._ The system cache clearer is used in the bin/console cache:clear command. The app clearer is the default clearer." from [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#clearing-the-cache)

Comment: @DonCallisto `cache:clear` will not clear all caches. Per the quoted documentation, it only uses the cache.system_clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/cache.html#clearing-the-cache) for the version of Symfony relevant to your question:

> To clear the cache you can use the bin/console cache:pool:clear [pool] command. That will remove all the entries from your storage and you will have to recalculate all the values. You can also group your pools into "cache clearers". There are 3 cache clearers by default:
>
> - cache.global_clearer
> - cache.system_clearer
> - cache.app_clearer
>
> The global clearer clears all the cache items in every pool. The system cache clearer is used in the bin/console cache:clear command. The app clearer is the default clearer.

This documentation also applies to the current version of Symfony at the time of this post (6.2).

You can see here that it states that the `cache:clear` command only clears the system cache (via the `cache.system_clearer`). So with your setup, it should not clear your `api_call_cache_pool` pool when `cache:clear` runs. Therefore, you shouldn't have to make any changes.

If you wanted to your deployment script to be more explicit you could run `cache:pool:clear cache.system_clearer` instead of `cache:clear`.